# Is there a formal name for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been using a matrix of the following form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which is just a circularly-shifted $I$ matrix minus another $I$ matrix. Essentially, a permutation matrix minus an identity. Is there a formal name for that?

Comment: The Antidentity, the source of all mathematical evil.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I have heard. It is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), though, and the permutation matrix alone without the $-I$ is sometimes called the *cyclic shift matrix*, *circulant generator* or *generator of the circulant algebra*.